# Saving multiple array data in excel in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to save four variables in an excel sheet for following MATLAB code. Need your help on the last part of the code to achieve the same. Thank you in advance.

```
clear all;
close all;
for k = 1:9
filename = sprintf('Data_F_Ind000%d.txt',k);
data = load (filename);
alldata = eemd(data(:,1),0.01,10);
I1 = alldata (1,:);
I2 = alldata (2,:);
I3 = alldata (3,:);
I4 = alldata (4,:);
end
xlswrite('imf.xlsx',I1,1);
xlswrite('imf.xlsx',I2,2);
xlswrite('imf.xlsx',I3,3);
xlswrite('imf.xlsx',I4,4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the function correctly

```
  xlswrite(<name of excel>, <matrix to save>, <sheet>, <range>)
```

for example:

```
%This writes your I1 matrix in the "yourExcelSheet" sheet into the
% "yourname.xlsx" file starting at the cell A1 and using all the space that
% matrix I1 needs to write
xlswrite ('yourname.xlsx',I1,'YourExcelSheet','A1');
```